# Does a container class deal with errors or just raise them?

Tags: python, error-handling

I am working on creating a pseudo-`Vector` class in Python and I'm wondering if I should be error checking and if so to what extent.

For example, when someone does the following:

```
vec = Vector(1,2,3,4)
# vec is now [1,2,3,4]
vec[100] = 12
```

What should happen with the `IndexError` that is generated by my `__setitem__`? Should my `__setitem__` contain:

```
if index < 0 or index >= len(self.vector):
    raise IndexError("Index out of bounds")
```

Or should it be

```
try:
    if index < 0 or index >= len(self.vector):
        raise IndexError("Index out of bounds")
except IndexError as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Is it generally the case that the user of a container class will handle errors, or should the container itself know to handle errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two scenarios to consider when your custom class wraps some other class (like a custom container class built on top of a `list`).

1. The wrapped class and the wrapper both have the same expectations for valid inputs, and should raise the same exceptions on invalid ones. In this situation, you don't need to handle the exception, since the one that the inner, wrapped class will raise is appropriate. The only possible reason you might want to handle such an exception is to hide the internal workings of your class (in which case you might want to `raise SomeException from None` in an exception handler to hide the inner details).
2. The wrapper should behave differently than the wrapped class. In this case you may need to either inspect and/or modify the the inputs ahead of time, or catch and suppress exceptions raised by the wrapped code. For example, lists allow negative indexes, if you don't want your container to do so, you will need to check that indexes passed in are not negative (and raise an `IndexError` if they are). Or alternatively, if you want to allow out of bounds indexes to wrap around without limitation (so that any index `i` is treated as `i % len(self.vector)`), you could use `try`/`except` statements to catch `IndexError`s raised by the inner list and retry with a modified index (though come to think of it, you probably would just modify the index unconditionally).

So, I don't think there is a single right answer. The details depend on how the behavior of your collection is supposed to work and how that differs from the list you are wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

If your container would silence errors (by handling them) you'd never find problems with code using your `Vector` incorrectly.

In other words, only handle the exception in the `Vector` class if assigning to indices out of bounds is *correct behaviour*, and part of the intended design of your container.

For the vast majority of use cases, your class should not handle the `IndexError`; trying to assign to an index out of bounds is a not valid use case.

Comment: Ok great, that's what I was beginning to think